How to handle image upload from form to server action Error: "Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components"
I am trying to parse a file from my client side form to my server action so that i can upload it, but i get the error Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components
My current solution but this only sends the file name:
function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    const parsedValues = {
      ...values,
      applicationDate: values.applicationDate, // Keep as string
      applicationDeadline: values.applicationDeadline || null, // Use null instead of undefined
      resume: values.resume ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values.resume)) : null,
      coverLetter: values.resume
        ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values.coverLetter))
        : null,
      // Ensure other optional fields have default values
      jobDescription: values.jobDescription || "",
      applicationLink: values.applicationLink || "",
      applicationNotes: values.applicationNotes || "",
      jobReferenceNumber: values.jobReferenceNumber || "",
      referralSource: values.referral ? values.referralSource : "",
      referralContact: values.referral ? values.referralContact : "",
    };
    createApplication(parsedValues);
  }

my server action
"use server";

import { IApplication } from "@/models/application";

async function createApplication(formData: FormData) {
  console.log(formData);
}

export { createApplication };


